# Writing a generalized code

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, logic

I have the following function where i hard code `if` conditions like `'AssignedTo','ClaimStatusId','ClaimTypeId'`.

So, the strCondition string has any of the values like `'AssignedTo','ClaimStatusId','ClaimTypeId'`, then it will be redirected to corresponding `if` conditions

```
function ChangeIDToString(strCondition,id)
    {
        if (strCondition.indexOf("AssignedTo") > -1)
            return GetUserName(id)
        else if (strCondition.indexOf("ClaimStatusId") > -1)
            return GetClaimStatus(id)
        else if (strCondition.indexOf("ClaimTypeId") > -1)
            return GetClaimType(id);           
        else
            return id;
    }
```

> Is there any way i can eliminate this hardcoded values like
>   'AssignedTo','ClaimStatusId','ClaimTypeId'?

Comment: Is strCondition is of type array ?

Comment: Pass `id` and `strvalue` in a single argument and then do split. Like `ClaimStatusId_{id}`

Answer (score 0):

An approach like this?

```
function ChangeIDToString(strCondition,id)
    {
        return _func[strCondition]();
    }

var _func = {
   "AssignedTo":function(){ GetUserName(); },
   "ClaimStatusId":function(){ GetClaimStatus(); }
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use an object to store the string values, of course it is still hard coded because it is impossible that the machine understands that it need to execute "GetUserName()" when the condition is "AssignedTo".

```
var Conditions = {
    GetUserName: "AssignedTo",
    GetClaimStatus: "ClaimStatusId",
    GetClaimType: "ClaimTypeId"
}
function ChangeIDToString(strCondition,id)
{
    if (strCondition.indexOf(Conditions.GetUserName) > -1)
        return GetUserName(id)
    else if (strCondition.indexOf(Conditions.GetClaimStatus) > -1)
        return GetClaimStatus(id)
    else if (strCondition.indexOf(Conditions.GetClaimType) > -1)
        return GetClaimType(id);           
    else
        return id;
}
```