# getting the length of an array with eval()-function?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why doesnt this work:

```
var problem_0 = ["a","b","c","d"];
arrayname = "problem_0";
arraylength = eval([arrayname]).length;
for (i = 0; i < arraylength; i++) {
```

I'm trying to retrieve different arrays depending on what the user click on, so i need *arrayname* to be a string, a string I can modify width a code. eval([arrayname]).length returns "1". Why?

Comment: Because `eval` returns this array:  `["problem_0"]`. Anyway, variables are not meant to be dynamically referred. Learn how to use object and its properties.

Comment: @Teemu Actually, dynamically created variables certainly are meant to be created. You just need to use array notation to do it. For example, this won't work:  var x = 10; var someObject = new Object(); someObject.x + 1 = "Property Name 11 was just set"; but this will: var x = 10; var someObject = new Object(); someObject[x + 1] = "Property Name 11 was just set";  https://jsfiddle.net/q86hd0o0/

Comment: @ScottMarcus Please re-read my comment: "variables are not meant to be dynamically _referred_". You're talking about properties of an object, which are totally different from variables.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Btw. After reading your comments to some answers here, [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34788914/1169519) seems to have a problem, which can't be solved without using `eval()`. If you can, please answer the question, I'm curious to see how that could be done.

Comment: @Teemu You're right, I am talking about creating an object property, and I'm talking about doing it by dynamically creating it using variables. Since all variables belong to a scope, all variables are actually properties of some object and thus my point applies. Creating and/or referring to dynamic variables are two sides of the same coin. As to the other post you point to, I'll take a closer look at it, but I can tell you that there is NO situation that requires eval. Often, the solution is to refactor the problem, rather than try to force a hack.

Comment: After looking at SmartestVEGA's post that you mention, I would say that #1 the post does not supply enough information about what the ultimate goal is to make a detailed suggestion and #2 if the function to be called is based on some literal value, then the literal value must exist somewhere. If I understand the question correctly, the user wants to have a solution that uses and doesn't use hard coded values. More info. is needed, but I can say that the structure of this problem screams for an implementation of the Strategy Pattern. As I said before, often you have to rethink structure of code

Comment: How about this: https://jsfiddle.net/m271cpum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use `eval` if the array has a global scope.

```
var problem_0 = ["a","b","c","d"];
arrayname = "problem_0";
alert(window[arrayname].length);
```

you can also use `this`

```
var a = [1,2];
var b = "a";
alert(this[b].length); //outputs 2
```

Comment: Thanks. I dont fully understand window, but have to read when to use eval and when to use window:-)

Comment: While eval() is part of the JavaScript language, its use is widely discouraged. There really isn't any problem that requires eval as a solution. The use of eval opens up security holes in an application and also introduces a new scope (execution context) into the execution stack.  There are many parts of JS that should be avoided and this one is at the top of the list.  window is simply the global object in a web browser - - everything lives within its global scope. When people talk about global in a browser, they are talking about the window object.

Comment: @gurvinder372 This really isn't a viable solution as nothing really should be in the global scope.

Comment: Even with your edit to "this", your solution will fail if the function containing the code you provide is invoked via .call(), .apply() or .bind(). My solution below works all the time and follows best-practices by breaking the solution out to its own function.

Answer (score 0):

eval() is EVIL and should not be used. Why don't you just pass the array in question to a function that receives it as an argument. Then that function can check the length of the passed array via the argument name? Problem solved.

```
var a1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
var a2 = [0,1,2,3];
var a3 = [0,1,];

function getArrayLength(a){
    return a.length;
}

getArrayLength(a1);
getArrayLength(a2);
getArrayLength(a3);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h6ehu5cc/

But, the direct answer to your question as to why your code doesn't work is because you wrote: `eval([arrayname]).length`, which takes the string and turns it into an array of the characters in the array's name (`["P","r","o","b","l","e","m","_","0"]`) when you should have written: `eval(arrayname).length`, which would evaluate the string name into an object reference and then the length of that object's members would be returned.

The following code shows how your eval version should work, but again I'm only showing it so you can see what you did, don't use eval in your solution for real though:

```
var problem_0 = ["a","b","c","d"];
arrayStringName = "problem_0";
arrayObjectName = eval(arrayStringName);
arraylength = arrayObjectName.length;
for (i = 0; i < arraylength; i++) { 
    alert(arrayObjectName[i]);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9n9552oe/

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to use eval - while not exactly evil, there are only three people in the world who fully understand how it works. (And one of them has forgotten...)

In the past ten years of javascript programming I've never had to use it - other methods are available.

As the previous answers show, you don't need it in this example.

Comment: eval IS evil. It's actually well understood by a great many developers, but what most developers don't understand is how to solve their problems without it, so they just hold their breath and use it anyway. eval()  opens up potential security holes and introduces new scope when (as you say) there is no problem that can't be solved without it.

Comment: Scott - Thanks for your superior knowledge - I wasn't aware of security issues - you are clearly one of the three that FULLY understand.

I only know I've never needed it...